# Problems about filter and lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote some codes in python to get some primes:

```
N = (x for x in range(2,100))

while i<50:
    n = next(N)
    print(n)
    N = filter(lambda x:x % n > 0,N)
    i = i+1
```

I think it should print primes 2,3,5,7,11....
But it turns out to be 2,3,4,5,6,7... Just like the filter didn't work.
I guess maybe it's a problems of lambda, which didn't provide the value of n successfully, so I just change my codes to these:

```
def fil(n):
    return lambda x:x % n > 0

N = (x for x in range(2,100))

i = 0
while i<50:
    n = next(N)
    print(n)
    N = filter(fil(n),N)
    i = i+1
```

It works.

But I still doubt that, so I wrote these:

```
N = (x for x in range(2,100))

i = 0
while i<50:
    n = next(N)
    print(n)
    N = filter(lambda x:x % n == 0,N)
    i = i+1
```

Just changed the lambda x:x % n > 0 to lambda x:x % n==0. Other parts are identical. And this time it works, gives me 2^x: 2,4,8,16,32... The filter works.

It really confused me. How to explain / understand this?

Comment: Side-note: `N = (x for x in range(2,100))` is an unnecessarily hand-rolled way to write `N = iter(range(2, 100))`. The latter will be a C level iterator on CPython, the former is executing byte code to produce each value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` on Python 3 is lazy, so the filter isn't applied until the next number is requested. When you don't use closure scope for the predicate, you end up using the live value of `n`, so you're effectively testing if each number is divisible by the previous number (that is, when testing 4, each `filter` wrapping is rechecking whether it's divisible by 3, 5 is checked for divisibility by 4 over and over, etc.), which is never the case (I strongly suspect your output never included `1` though, since your original genexpr doesn't even produce 1).

The simplest fix to your original code is to use a default argument to bind `n` at function definition time, rather than referencing it in the body of the function, which looks it up in nested scope at call time, getting a live value. All you have to do is change:

```
N = filter(lambda x: x % n > 0, N)
```

to:

```
N = filter(lambda x, n=n: x % n > 0, N)
```

Comment: oh sorry , it's not 1,2,3... but start from 2.  Edited.

Comment: Then ,how to explain filter(lambda x:x % n == 0,N) works?

Comment: @B.Law: It's the exact same thing. Each number is being tested for divisibility by the previous number to pass the test. So 2 passes, then 3 is tested (and found to have a remainder, so it's filtered out), 4 is tested (and has no remainder, passing and changing `n`) and printed. The 5, 6, 7, and 8 are all tested (repeatedly, due to multiple `filter` wrappings) for divisibility by 4, and 8 is the next to pass. Conveniently, for powers of 2, testing divisibility by the previous power of two prevents anything from passing until the next power of two; you don't need to test anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.I realized I misunderstood how filter works.